# Need Help Getting A Simple Stop-Watch Working?

Tags: java, swing, timer

So I am experimenting with a little stop-watch object and I can't figure out why it isn't working. I have a gui with the following;
timeinfield is a jtextfield which the user enters the start time of the clock.
timerfield is a jtextfield where the clock is displayed timing.
startbutton is a jbutton where the user clicks to start the clock.
stopbutton is a jbutton where the user clicks to stop the clock.

Right now, the timerfield just displays Running: 0 seconds.
Nothing else happens, maybe I am doing this wrong for it is my first time trying something like this. I am about to start learning how to use threads so I thought this might help get me started.

```
  private void startbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        String starttim = timeinfield.getText();
        long startTime = Long.valueOf(starttim);
        boolean running = false;
        Timer timer = null;

        long time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000;

        timerfield.setText("Running:" + time + "seconds");
        if (running==false) {
           running = true;
           timerfield.setText("Running: 0 seconds");
        }
        if (stopbutton.isSelected()) {
            timer.stop();
            running = false;
            long endTime = evt.getWhen();
            double seconds = (endTime - startTime)/1000.0;
            timerfield.setText("Time: " + seconds + "sec.");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It displays only "Running: 0 seconds" because after `timerfield.setText("Running: 0 seconds");` you never update the GUI.

Also, you attempt to perform `timer.stop();` while timer is null, this will cause NullPointerException.

And one more thing: running will be false every time you click the button, since it is a local variable and it is initialized to false every time. If you want it to be permanent, move it out of the method, and initialize it outside.

Answer (score 1):

You never start a Timer that actually does the job of updating the field.

Answer (score -1):

Several thingies wrong with your code, some already spotted :-) All have a common reason:

*you don't seem to have a good understanding of what you are doing ;-)*

My suggestion would be to take the first step of any successful undertaking: read the relevant chapter of your textbook/tutorial *carefully* In the context of Swing reading Snoracle's online tutorial is a *must* For learning to use Timers the relevant chapter is

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Next step is to apply what you learned to your context, starting simple (f.i leave out the ability to type in the start time) and identiying the parts you need and keep separate parts separate! Hint: you need 3 actionListeners. Only when you have a simple example running, add complexity, one by one. Rinse, repeat ...

Oh ... and learn and stick to java naming conventions! Not doing so makes it hard to read the code, even for yourself :-)